# Is there a way to find out if a certain file has been copied into USB memory stick?

Tags: linux, logging, archlinux

I am using Arch linux.
I am wondering if there are log files or other ways to find out if some files has been copied or moved into USB memory stick.
I know /var/log keep log files and tested by coping a file into USB stick.
But, the following command did not show me anything.

```
find /var/log -type f | xargs grep 'file name'
```

Any hint might be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I was not aware of those sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

It's quite a hard problem to detect a user opening one file for read, another for write, and copying the file.  (Off the top of my head, they could use tar, cp, cat, dd, head, tail, less, tee, sed, perl, python, awk, etc, etc.)  Particularly as the data written doesn't need to be the same as the wrote.